# Проблема в работе функции fscanf

Tags: c, строки, структуры, ввод

Возникла проблема при считывании строк из файла. Вот код:

```
#define SIZE 15
#define MAX 20

struct new
{
    char surname[SIZE];
    char name[4];
}user_str[MAX_RECORD];
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%s %s\n",user_str[i].surname, user_str[i].name);

    }
    printf("%s %s\n",  user_str[0].surname, user_str[0].name);
```

Объясню суть программы: дан текстовый файл, в котором находится две строки и в них написаны: Фамилия Имя Отчество, в формате: Family I.O. 
Необходимо считать данный файл и записать данные в структуру.

Для примера, текстовый файл выглядит так:
Ivanov I.I.
Petrov K.K.

Однако при попытке вывести `user_str[0].surname, user_str[0].name` выводит `Ivanov I.I.Petrov`, а должен просто `Ivanov I.I`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум `name` у вас - 4 символа, и читаете вы в него 4 символа. А куда записывается нулевой завершающий символ? Да, именно - *за пределами* структуры. Скорее всего, уже в следующую структуру - а там забивается вводом очередной фамилии. Вот вы ее и получаете...

Не жалейте памяти. А то вдруг у вас будет О.С.Б.М. Бендер-Задунайский - сами видите, что ваших размеров не хватит. Лучше использовать безопасные функции в духе `_s` или иным образом следить, сколько символов вводится - переполнение буфера - просто приглашение для неприятностей заглянуть в гости...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, приму к сведению)